# Getting gtk.gdk.window.handle on Windows

Tags: video, gtk, pygtk, vlc

I'm working on a simple video player in Python and PyGTK, using VLC as player backend. I want to show the video image in a gtk.DrawingArea so, in Linux, I use **builder.get_object('drawingarea1').window.xid** to get the XID of the DrawingArea widget. In Windows, according to documentation, I have to use **builder.get_object('drawingarea1').window.handle**, but when I start to play a video file, it gets played in the whole window, not just in the gtk.DrawingArea. I started digging to find what's happening and I found that the number retrieved from **builder.get_object('mainWindow').window.handle** is the same with **builder.get_object('drawingarea1').window.handle**. Is this the right method to get the handler of a widget, or I do something wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch, but try placing the drawing area on a GtkEventBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you've done without an example, however I did a bit of searching and found this question and possible answer here http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/gtk-DrawingArea-handle-id-on-win32-bug-td1943074.html.  And an example was attached. The link http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.18/gtk-migrating-ClientSideWindows.html he provides does not exist any more, but I found a updated link http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-migrating-ClientSideWindows.html.  Essentially it seems you must call

```
drawingarea.window.ensure_native()
```

to make the

```
drawingarea.window.handle
```

attribute return the correct native handle of the drawingarea

On Linux getting the attribute

```
drawingarea.window.xid
```

automatically calls

```
drawingarea.window.ensure_native()
```

but

```
drawingarea.window.handle
```

does not do this for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Also, I'm having another issue: if I hide the player's window and I display it again (it's a "hide to systray" feature) the video never shows up again, until I destroy the gtk.Drawingarea and recreate it. What could be the issue here?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know.  Have you tried calling drawingarea.window.ensure_native() again?  That's all I can think of.  It might be also that the handle is destroyed when it's hidden, so you might need to see if the handle is the same after calling ensure_native(), and make sure you're handle pointer points to the right one.  Just an educated guess.  Let me know if what I said works.

Comment: The handle id seems to remain the same before and after hiding the video window. Calling again ensure_native() didn't help. I asked on VLC forums and they say that this is a GTK issue... so I guess that I just have to be happy with this.

Comment: Thanks, That's useful to know.  Yes, I guess, unless you're willing to fix the bug in the windows port of GTK, I agree with having to be happy with what you have.